# Elm 0.16 to 0.18 Http.get?

Tags: elm

I've been trying to convert my Elm 0.16 code to 0.18. However I can't seem to get the Http.get I had to work.

The old code was:

```
fetch : Decoder a -> String -> (Result Http.Error a -> b) -> Effects b --Effects became Cmd in 0.17
fetch decoder url action =
    Http.get decoder url
    |> Task.toResult
    |> Task.map action
    |> Effects.task
```

But Task.toResult doesn't exist anymore.
I found a [google groups conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/elm-discuss/gkdCrioDsUQ/cJn5-n6fFQAJ) that stated I had to convert

`task |> Task.toResult |> Task.map action |> Effects.task` to

`task |> Task.toResult |> Task.perform never action`

But then I still get the "`Task` does not expose `toResult`" error since in 0.18 they removed that it seems.

How can I fix this? I've tried searching the web, but find everything very confusing and not very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to use [`Http.get`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/latest/Http#get) and [`Http.send`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/latest/Http#send) for your `fetch` function:

```elm
fetch : Decoder a -> String -> (Result Http.Error a -> b) -> Cmd b
fetch decoder url action =
    Http.get url decoder
        |> Http.send action
```

Since 0.16, the `Http` package does not require you to use an intermediate `Task` before sending the request. You can still convert a request to a `Task` if needed by using [`Http.toTask`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/latest/Http#toTask), in case you want to chain together multiple requests.